# How to generate Schema.json for Apollo graphQL iOS | local host

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

I am new to GraphQL and created a hello world server application (spring boot) which is running on local host on my machine

I wanna use those endpoints in my iOS app but I have no clue **how to generate a schema.json file** if I use Apollo iOS client? I followed multiple tutorials but couldn't understand this point. The schema on my server looks like:

```
type Person {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    title: String
    employmentDate: String
    telephoneNumber: String
}

type Query {
  getData(n: Int) : Hello
  getAll:[Person]

}

schema {
 query: Query
 mutation: Mutation
 subscription: Subscription
}
```

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema/